# Java: The method keyPressed(KeyEvent) in the type <classname> is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Tags: java

I'm beginner-ish in java, and I tried to achieve the following: My program is constantly running in the background (so it's not even the active window), and when I press Enter, it prints out a text. My problem can be seen in the title, which displays when I hover over "keyPressed" in my main method (I'm using eclipse). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, maybe I completely misunderstood how this is supposed to be working.

```
public class Test implements KeyListener {

    private static boolean done = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(!done) {
            keyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("I got it working! I think.");
        done = true;

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `KeyEvent.VK_ENTER` is an int anf keyPressed method taking type of KeyEvent

Answer (score 0):

You are calling inner method com.dish.wsapi.WsapiJsonFileCreate.keyPressed(KeyEvent) which has Key Event as input ,But you are passing an integer value java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER

Answer (score 0):

KeyEvent.VK_ENTER is defined as an int value corresponding to the key code of the return key on your keyboard. A correct implementation would be to create a new KeyEvent object and assign KeyEvent.VK_ENTER as the keycode to the object before passing it as an argument.

```
Test obj = new Test();
KeyEvent e = new KeyEvent(new JButton(), 0, 0, 0, KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, '\0');
obj.keyPressed(e);
```

Comment: Alright, I did this, and now I'm getting a different error:

Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method keyPressed(KeyEvent) from the type <classname>

If I change the keyPressed method to static, then suddenly it wants me to remove @override, and if I change KeyEvent e to static, then that becomes the problem. What can I do now?

Comment: Yeah, you need to create an object of type Test and invoke the method on that object.

Comment: I'm ashamed that I don't know what you meant by that, since I thought that I understood at least this much in Java. Could you explain this a bit beginner-friendlier?

Comment: keyPressed() is a member function of the class Test. Before you can invoke this method, you need to specify an object created from this class. I.E. Test testobj = new Test(); testobj.keyPressed(e);

Comment: It apparently isn't accepting "null" as a Component. After researching this a bit, a component appears to be some kind of graphics element, but the problem is that I've only ever made programs which explicitly used the command prompt.What should I write in the place of "null, 0, 0, 0," exactly? I'm kind of lost now.

Comment: This worked in a test program I built: 
  KeyEvent e = new KeyEvent(new JButton(), 0, 0, 0, 0, '\0');
  KeyEventTesting testobj = new KeyEventTesting();
  testobj.keyPressed(e);

Comment: Thank you, I got it working, albeit I just realized that it's impossible in Java to detect keypresses while the window is not visible. Which kind of sucks.